# Range of a piano : annotate note frequency

Tags: music

I'd like to draw something [like this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Range_of_piano.svg) for the piano, but with all notes explicitly draw and labelled with its [frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_key_frequencies). I use for the first time the [`musixtex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/musixtex) package so I have no idea how to automate the annotation.

Here is what I've done so far.

```
\documentclass[preview,border={3cm 2mm 3cm 2mm}]{standalone}% standalone works with adjusting the border.
\usepackage{musixtex}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\instrumentnumber{1}
\setstaffs{1}{2}
\setclef{1}{60}
%
\startextract
\notes\qu{`CDEFG 'AB}\enotes
\bar
\notes\qu{CDEFG 'AB}\enotes
\bar
\notes\qu{'CDEFG 'AB}\enotes
\bar
\notes|\qu{cdefg'ab}\enotes
\bar
\notes|\qu{'cdefg 'ab}\enotes
\zendextract
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On a different note, do you know lilypond? (http://www.lilypond.org) This is a very sophisticated notation software.

Comment: @Bugbusters Thanks for editing. The thing with standalone is why is it necessary to adjust the border (maybe I'll ask an other question).

Comment: @biologue I'm not stuck with a `musixtex` answer. If lilypond can do the job, that's ok `;-)`.

Comment: What is your reference frequency for A? 440, 442,...?

Comment: Unrelated: why don't the stems change their orientation at d and b'?

Comment: @AndrewSwann It does not matter. Say 440Hz.

Comment: @doncherry The `\qu` in the MWE explicitly draws quarter notes with stem up. There are also `\ql` for a quarter notes with stem down and `\qa` for quarter notes with automatic stem direction.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood the question right and this is what you want but here we go: the code uses the fact that a pitch cannot only be specified with a letter but also with a number. The frequencies are calculated with the formula on the linked Wikipedia site. (I don't know why the margins for `standalone` have to be enlarged manually to see the whole extract...).

```
% arara: musixtex
\documentclass[preview,border={17cm 2mm 17cm 2mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% define integer variables:
\int_new:N \l__cjorssen_pitch_int
\int_new:N \l__cjorssen_step_int

% define tokenlist variable for the formatted output of the
% frequencies:
\tl_new:N  \l__cjorssen_freq_format_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l__cjorssen_freq_format_tl { \tiny\bfseries }

% macro to write notes and frequencies for one octave
%   #1: the lowest pitch
%   #2: the highest pitch, should not be more than #1+6
%   #3: the difference between pitch number and key number
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cjorssen_write_notes:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    % set the starting pitch:
    \int_set:Nn \l__cjorssen_pitch_int { #1 }
    % set the step to zero:
    \int_zero:N \l__cjorssen_step_int
    % loop until we reach the end pitch:
    \int_do_while:nn { \l__cjorssen_pitch_int <= #2 }
      {
        % \cchar{<pitch>}{<something>} is a musixtex macro that
        % allows setting <something> at the specified <pitch>
        % let's set the frequency below the tone it belongs to:
        \cchar
          { \int_eval:n { \l__cjorssen_pitch_int - 5 } }
          {
            % start a group to keep the format local, just in case
            \group_begin:
              % the format:
              \tl_use:N \l__cjorssen_freq_format_tl
              % let's test at which point of the octave we are
              % and add the needed integer to \l__cjorssen_pitch_int
              % in order to get the right key number with respect to
              % musixtex's pitch number:
              \int_case:nnn { \l__cjorssen_step_int }
                {
                  { 0 } { \cjorssen_calc_freq:n { \l__cjorssen_pitch_int + #3 } }
                  { 1 } { \cjorssen_calc_freq:n { \l__cjorssen_pitch_int + 1 + #3 } }
                  { 2 } { \cjorssen_calc_freq:n { \l__cjorssen_pitch_int + 2 + #3 } }
                  { 3 } { \cjorssen_calc_freq:n { \l__cjorssen_pitch_int + 2 + #3 } }
                  { 4 } { \cjorssen_calc_freq:n { \l__cjorssen_pitch_int + 3 + #3 } }
                  { 5 } { \cjorssen_calc_freq:n { \l__cjorssen_pitch_int + 4 + #3 } }
                  { 6 } { \cjorssen_calc_freq:n { \l__cjorssen_pitch_int + 5 + #3 } }
                }
                {}
              \,Hz
            \group_end:
          }
        % write the note:
        \qu { \int_use:N \l__cjorssen_pitch_int }
        % step the integers for the next round in the loop:
        \int_incr:N \l__cjorssen_step_int
        \int_incr:N \l__cjorssen_pitch_int
      }
  }

% calculate the frequency from the key number
% (using 440Hz for the concert pitch):
\cs_new:Npn \cjorssen_calc_freq:n #1
  { \fp_eval:n { round ( 440 * 2^(((#1)-49)/12) , 2 ) } }

% #1: the lowest pitch
% #2: the highest pitch, should not be more than #1+6
% #3: the difference between pitch number and key number
\NewDocumentCommand \writenotes { mO{#1+6}m }
  { \cjorssen_write_notes:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{music}
 \instrumentnumber{1}
 \setstaffs{1}{2}
 \setclef{1}{60}
 \setname{1}{}
 \startextract
 \NOTes
  \writenotes{-11}{15}
 \en\bar
 \NOTes
  \writenotes{-4}{20}
 \en\bar
 \NOTes
  \writenotes{3}{25}
 \en\bar
 \NOTEs|
  \writenotes{-2}{42}
 \en\bar
 \NOTEs|
  \writenotes{5}{47}
 \en
 \endextract
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the same with the `article` class:

```
% arara: musixtex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% define integer variables:
\int_new:N \l__cjorssen_pitch_int
\int_new:N \l__cjorssen_step_int

% define tokenlist variable for the formatted output of the
% frequencies:
\tl_new:N  \l__cjorssen_freq_format_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l__cjorssen_freq_format_tl { \tiny\bfseries }

% macro to write notes and frequencies for one octave
%   #1: the lowest pitch
%   #2: the highest pitch, should not be more than #1+6
%   #3: the difference between pitch number and key number
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cjorssen_write_notes:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    % set the starting pitch:
    \int_set:Nn \l__cjorssen_pitch_int { #1 }
    % set the step to zero:
    \int_zero:N \l__cjorssen_step_int
    % loop until we reach the end pitch:
    \int_do_while:nn { \l__cjorssen_pitch_int <= #2 }
      {
        % \cchar{<pitch>}{<something>} is a musixtex macro that
        % allows setting <something> at the specified <pitch>
        % let's set the frequency below the tone it belongs to:
        \cchar
          { \int_eval:n { \l__cjorssen_pitch_int - 5 } }
          {
            % start a group to keep the format local, just in case
            \group_begin:
              % the format:
              \tl_use:N \l__cjorssen_freq_format_tl
              % let's test at which point of the octave we are
              % and add the needed integer to \l__cjorssen_pitch_int
              % in order to get the right key number with respect to
              % musixtex's pitch number:
              \int_case:nnn { \l__cjorssen_step_int }
                {
                  { 0 } { \cjorssen_calc_freq:n { \l__cjorssen_pitch_int + #3 } }
                  { 1 } { \cjorssen_calc_freq:n { \l__cjorssen_pitch_int + 1 + #3 } }
                  { 2 } { \cjorssen_calc_freq:n { \l__cjorssen_pitch_int + 2 + #3 } }
                  { 3 } { \cjorssen_calc_freq:n { \l__cjorssen_pitch_int + 2 + #3 } }
                  { 4 } { \cjorssen_calc_freq:n { \l__cjorssen_pitch_int + 3 + #3 } }
                  { 5 } { \cjorssen_calc_freq:n { \l__cjorssen_pitch_int + 4 + #3 } }
                  { 6 } { \cjorssen_calc_freq:n { \l__cjorssen_pitch_int + 5 + #3 } }
                }
                {}
              \,Hz
            \group_end:
          }
        % write the note:
        \qu { \int_use:N \l__cjorssen_pitch_int }
        % step the integers for the next round in the loop:
        \int_incr:N \l__cjorssen_step_int
        \int_incr:N \l__cjorssen_pitch_int
      }
  }

% calculate the frequency from the key number
% (using 440Hz for the concert pitch):
\cs_new:Npn \cjorssen_calc_freq:n #1
  { \fp_eval:n { round ( 440 * 2^(((#1)-49)/12) , 2 ) } }

% #1: the lowest pitch
% #2: the highest pitch, should not be more than #1+6
% #3: the difference between pitch number and key number
\NewDocumentCommand \writenotes { mO{#1+6}m }
  { \cjorssen_write_notes:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{music}
 \instrumentnumber{1}
 \setstaffs{1}{2}
 \setclef{1}{60}
 \setname{1}{}
 \startpiece
 \NOTes
  \writenotes{-11}{15}
 \en\alaligne
 \NOTes
  \writenotes{-4}{20}
 \en\alaligne
 \NOTes
  \writenotes{3}{25}
 \en\alaligne
 \NOTEs|
  \writenotes{-2}{42}
 \en\alaligne
 \NOTEs|
  \writenotes{5}{47}
 \en
 \endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think your correspondence between the notes and the key numbers used in the formula is correct. The A above middle C should be ~440 Hz.

Comment: @AlanMunn corrected ... I hope

Comment: Not quite, you're still one octave off.  The A440 should be on the first space of the treble clef.

Comment: @AlanMunn Oh `&%$?`! The last two times the `difference between pitch number and key number` arguments need to be increased by twelve to `42` and `47`, respectively. At least the code seems to work...

Comment: Sorry, I meant *second* space of the treble clef.

Comment: @cgnieder Thank you very much for your efforts. That's what I need. Would you mind decyphering some bits of the `LaTeX3` code, particularly how the tokens are given back to musictex.

Comment: @cjorssen I added explanations to the code