# Type1 fonts and musixtex

Tags: fonts, mathdesign, music, type1

Thanks to @cgnieder, I can now typeset [the full range of a piano](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111068/8425). Now, I'd like to use the `utopia-mathdesign` package.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\instrumentnumber{1}
\setstaffs{1}{2}
\setclef{1}{60}
%
\startextract
\notes|\qu{cdefg'ab}\enotes
\zendextract
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, LaTeX fails with

```
[skipped beginning of log file]
MusiXTeX(c) 1.15 <3 April 2011>

kpathsea: Running mktextfm mdr0800
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input mdr0800
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2012)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf mdr0800
! I can't find file `mdr0800'.
<*> ...=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input mdr0800

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input mdr0800

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: mdr0800.log: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input mdr0800' failed to make mdr0800.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/musixtex/musixtex.tex:575: Font 
\eightrm=mdr0800 not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   \font 
l.575   \font
             \eightbf=\fontid bx0800
?
```

It's been a while since I encountered such problems. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use it the other way round:

```
\documentclass{standalone}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{musixtex}     
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}     
[ ... ]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you explain why?