# Tikz configuration for Piano lesson chart (tones and semi tones)

Tags: tikz-pgf, musixtex

The expected output should be:
[image]

The current code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras


%Rutinas para dibujar el piano
\newlength{\CtoBwd}%% Width of 7 adjacent white (natural) keys
\newlength{\Whitewd}%% Width of a natural key
\newlength{\Blackwd}%% Width of a black key
\newlength{\Whitefrontht}%% Distance from front of white key to black key
\newlength{\Backwdi}%% <<-- See below
\newlength{\Backwdii}%% <<-- See below
\newlength{\Backwdiii}%% <<-- See below
\newlength{\FronttoBack}%% Total length of a natural key
\newlength{\Blackht}%% Length of a black key

%% http://datagenetics.com/blog/may32016/index.html

\NewDocumentCommand{\drawaccidental}{mmmm}{% Lower left, sharp name, flat name, coordinate name for upper right of accidental
    \draw[fill=black] (#1)
        rectangle node[white,text width=\Backwdii,align=center]
            {\bfseries\huge#2${}^\sharp$\\[1ex]#3${}^\flat$}
        ++ (\Blackwd,\Blackht)coordinate (#4);
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\drawname}{m}{% Coordinate name of lower left of key and name of key
    \node at ($(#1) + (\Whitewd/2,\Whitefrontht/2)$) {\bfseries\Huge#1};
}

%% f b = \Backwdi
%% cs ds fs gs as = \Backwdii
%% d g a = \Backwdii
%% c e = \Backwdiii

\NewDocumentCommand{\drawkeyboard}{}{%
    \draw (0,0)coordinate(C) -- ++(0,\FronttoBack) -- ++(\Backwdiii,0) --
        ++(0,-\Blackht)coordinate(CS) -| (\Whitewd,0)coordinate(D) -- cycle;
    \drawaccidental{CS}{C}{D}{CS0}
    \drawname{C}

    \draw (D) -- ++(0,\Whitefrontht) -| (CS0) -- ++(\Backwdii,0) -- ++(0,-\Blackht)coordinate(DS)
        -| (2\Whitewd,0)coordinate(E) -- cycle;
    \drawaccidental{DS}{D}{E}{DS0}
    \drawname{D}

    \draw (E) -- ++(0,\Whitefrontht) -| (DS0) -- ++(\Backwdiii,0) -- ++(0,-\FronttoBack)coordinate(F)
        -- cycle;
    \drawname {E}

    \draw (F) -- ++(0,\FronttoBack) -- ++(\Backwdi,0) -- ++(0,-\Blackht)coordinate(FS)
        -| (4\Whitewd,0)coordinate(G) -- cycle;
    \drawaccidental{FS}{F}{G}{FS0}
    \drawname{F}

    \draw (G) -- ++(0,\Whitefrontht) -| (FS0) -- ++(\Backwdii,0) -- ++(0,-\Blackht)coordinate(GS)
        -| (5\Whitewd,0)coordinate(A) -- cycle;
    \drawaccidental{GS}{G}{A}{GS0}
    \drawname{G}

    \draw (A) -- ++(0,\Whitefrontht) -| (GS0) -- ++(\Backwdii,0) -- ++(0,-\Blackht)coordinate(AS)
    -| (6\Whitewd,0)coordinate(B) -- cycle;
    \drawaccidental{AS}{A}{B}{AS0}
    \drawname{A}

    \draw (B) -- ++(0,\Whitefrontht) -| (AS0) -- ++(\Backwdi,0) -- ++(0,-\FronttoBack) -- cycle;
    \drawname{B}
}

\begin{document}

%Dibujo del piano
\setlength{\CtoBwd}{6.5in} %% This varies between 160mm to 167mm depending upon manufacturer
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\tmpwd}{\CtoBwd/5880}\typeout{\tmpwd!!!!}
\setlength{\Whitewd}{\dimexpr \tmpwd*840\relax}
\setlength{\Blackwd}{\dimexpr \tmpwd*490\relax}
\setlength{\Blackht}{3.75in}
\setlength{\Whitefrontht}{2in}
\setlength{\FronttoBack}{\dimexpr \Whitefrontht + \Blackht\relax}
\setlength{\Backwdi}{\dimexpr\tmpwd*455\relax}
\setlength{\Backwdii}{\dimexpr\tmpwd*490\relax}
\setlength{\Backwdiii}{\dimexpr\tmpwd*525\relax}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7,rounded corners=4pt]
    %\foreach \oct in {0,...,3}{% for 4 octaves; vary at will
    \foreach \oct in {0}{% for 4 octaves; vary at will
        \begin{scope}[xshift=\oct*\CtoBwd]
        \drawkeyboard
        \end{scope}
    }
    %Poniendo etiquetas
    \node[text width=1cm,align=center] (tonoCD) at (2.35,-1.0) {\textbf{1 tono}};
    \node[text width=1cm,align=center] (tonoDE) at (4.7,-1.0) {\textbf{1 tono}};
    \node[text width=1cm,align=center] (semiTonoEF) at (7.1,-1.0) {\textbf{$1/2$ tono}};
    \node[text width=1cm,align=center] (tonoFG) at (9.4,-1.0) {\textbf{1 tono}};
    \node[text width=1cm,align=center] (tonoGA) at (11.8,-1.0) {\textbf{1 tono}};
    \node[text width=1cm,align=center] (tonoAB) at (14.2,-1.0) {\textbf{1 tono}};
    \node[text width=1cm,align=center] (semiTonoBC) at (16.5,-1.0) {\textbf{$1/2$ tono}};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

I need to improve the code for the following issues:

1. Add border and background collor for labels: tones and semitones.
2. Change the notes for spanish: Do for C, Re for D, Mi for E, and so on.
3. Reduce the high size of the piano.

The current code output is:

[image: current code output]

Thanks and Regards

Comment: 1. `\node[text width=1cm,align=center,draw,fill=red!20]` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc,positioning}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras


% Rutinas para dibujar el piano
\newlength{\CtoBwd}%% Width of 7 adjacent white (natural) keys
\newlength{\Whitewd}%% Width of a natural key
\newlength{\Blackwd}%% Width of a black key
\newlength{\Whitefrontht}%% Distance from front of white key to black key
\newlength{\Backwdi}%% <<-- See below
\newlength{\Backwdii}%% <<-- See below
\newlength{\Backwdiii}%% <<-- See below
\newlength{\FronttoBack}%% Total length of a natural key
\newlength{\Blackht}%% Length of a black key

%% http://datagenetics.com/blog/may32016/index.html

\NewDocumentCommand{\drawaccidental}{mmmm}{% Lower left, sharp name, flat name, coordinate name for upper right of accidental
  \draw[fill=black] (#1)
  rectangle node[white,text width=\Backwdii,align=center]
  {\bfseries\large#2$^\sharp$\\[1ex]#3$^\flat$}
  ++ (\Blackwd,\Blackht)coordinate (#4);
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\drawname}{m}{% Coordinate name of lower left of key and name of key
  \node at ($(#1) + (\Whitewd/2,\Whitefrontht/2)$) {\bfseries\large#1};
}

%% f b = \Backwdi
%% cs ds fs gs as = \Backwdii
%% d g a = \Backwdii
%% c e = \Backwdiii

\NewDocumentCommand{\drawkeyboard}{}{%
\draw (0,0)coordinate(Do) -- ++(0,\FronttoBack) -- ++(\Backwdiii,0) --
  ++(0,-\Blackht)coordinate(DoS) -| (\Whitewd,0)coordinate(Re) -- cycle;
  \drawaccidental{DoS}{Do}{Re}{DoS0}
  \drawname{Do}
  
  \draw (Re) -- ++(0,\Whitefrontht) -| (DoS0) -- ++(\Backwdii,0) -- ++(0,-\Blackht)coordinate(ReS)
  -| (2\Whitewd,0)coordinate(Mi) -- cycle;
  \drawaccidental{ReS}{Re}{Mi}{ReS0}
  \drawname{Re}
  
  \draw (Mi) -- ++(0,\Whitefrontht) -| (ReS0) -- ++(\Backwdiii,0) -- ++(0,-\FronttoBack)coordinate(Fa)
  -- cycle;
  \drawname {Mi}
  
  \draw (Fa) -- ++(0,\FronttoBack) -- ++(\Backwdi,0) -- ++(0,-\Blackht)coordinate(FaS)
  -| (4\Whitewd,0)coordinate(Sol) -- cycle;
  \drawaccidental{FaS}{Fa}{Sol}{FaS0}
  \drawname{Fa}
  
  \draw (Sol) -- ++(0,\Whitefrontht) -| (FaS0) -- ++(\Backwdii,0) -- ++(0,-\Blackht)coordinate(SolS)
  -| (5\Whitewd,0)coordinate(La) -- cycle;
  \drawaccidental{SolS}{Sol}{La}{SolS0}
  \drawname{Sol}
  
  \draw (La) -- ++(0,\Whitefrontht) -| (SolS0) -- ++(\Backwdii,0) -- ++(0,-\Blackht)coordinate(LaS)
  -| (6\Whitewd,0)coordinate(Si) -- cycle;
  \drawaccidental{LaS}{La}{Si}{LaS0}
  \drawname{La}
  
  \draw (Si) -- ++(0,\Whitefrontht) -| (LaS0) -- ++(\Backwdi,0) -- ++(0,-\FronttoBack)coordinate(Do1) -- cycle;
  \drawname{Si}
}

% Dibujo del piano
\setlength{\CtoBwd}{6.5in} %% This varies between 160mm to 167mm depending upon manufacturer
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\tmpwd}{\CtoBwd/5880}\typeout{\tmpwd!!!!}
\setlength{\Whitewd}{\dimexpr \tmpwd*840\relax}
\setlength{\Blackwd}{\dimexpr \tmpwd*490\relax}
\setlength{\Blackht}{1.5in}
\setlength{\Whitefrontht}{1in}
\setlength{\FronttoBack}{\dimexpr \Whitefrontht + \Blackht\relax}
\setlength{\Backwdi}{\dimexpr\tmpwd*455\relax}
\setlength{\Backwdii}{\dimexpr\tmpwd*490\relax}
\setlength{\Backwdiii}{\dimexpr\tmpwd*525\relax}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7,rounded corners=4pt]
  % \foreach \oct in {0,...,3}{% for 4 octaves; vary at will
  \foreach \oct in {0}{% for 4 octaves; vary at will
    \begin{scope}[xshift=\oct*\CtoBwd]
      \drawkeyboard
    \end{scope}
  }
  % Poniendo etiquetas
  \tikzset{
    space/.style={text width=1cm,align=center,draw,below=2mm of #1},
    tono/.style={space=#1,fill=red!20},
    semitono/.style={space=#1,fill=yellow!70},
  }
  \node[tono=Re] (tonoDoRe) {\textbf{1 tono}};
  \node[tono=Mi] (tonoReMi) {\textbf{1 tono}};
  \node[semitono=Fa] (semiTonoMiFa) {\textbf{$1/2$ tono}};
  \node[tono=Sol] (tonoFaSol) {\textbf{1 tono}};
  \node[tono=La] (tonoSolLa) {\textbf{1 tono}};
  \node[tono=Si] (tonoLaSi) {\textbf{1 tono}};
  \node[semitono=Do1] (semiTonoSiDo) {\textbf{$1/2$ tono}};
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `musixtex` parts are not relevant to this solution, mostly based on this [sgmoye's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527410/161015).

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{tgchorus}% added <<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527410/161015
%Rutinas para dibujar el piano
\newlength{\CtoBwd}%% Width of 7 adjacent white (natural) keys
\newlength{\Whitewd}%% Width of a natural key
\newlength{\Blackwd}%% Width of a black key
\newlength{\Whitefrontht}%% Distance from front of white key to black key
\newlength{\Backwdi}%% <<-- See below
\newlength{\Backwdii}%% <<-- See below
\newlength{\Backwdiii}%% <<-- See below
\newlength{\FronttoBack}%% Total length of a natural key
\newlength{\Blackht}%% Length of a black key

\NewDocumentCommand{\drawaccidental}{mmmm}{% Lower left, sharp name, flat name, coordinate name for upper right of accidental
    \draw[fill=black] (#1) rectangle node{}++ (\Blackwd,\Blackht) coordinate (#4);
    }

\NewDocumentCommand{\drawname}{m}{% Coordinate name of lower left of key and name of key
    \node[font=\bfseries\large] at ($(#1) + (\Whitewd/2,\Whitefrontht/2)$) {#1};
    }

\NewDocumentCommand{\drawkeyboard}{}{% names of notes in spanish <<<< <<<<<<<<<<
    \draw (0,0)coordinate(DO) -- ++(0,\FronttoBack) -- ++(\Backwdiii,0) --
    ++(0,-\Blackht)coordinate(CS) -| (\Whitewd,0)coordinate(RE) -- cycle;
    \drawaccidental{CS}{}{}{CS0}
    \drawname{DO}
    
    \draw (RE) -- ++(0,\Whitefrontht) -| (CS0) -- ++(\Backwdii,0) -- ++(0,-\Blackht)coordinate(DS)
    -| (2\Whitewd,0)coordinate(MI) -- cycle;
    \drawaccidental{DS}{}{}{DS0}
    \drawname{RE}
    
    \draw (MI) -- ++(0,\Whitefrontht) -| (DS0) -- ++(\Backwdiii,0) -- ++(0,-\FronttoBack)coordinate(FA)
    -- cycle;
    \drawname {MI}
    
    \draw (FA) -- ++(0,\FronttoBack) -- ++(\Backwdi,0) -- ++(0,-\Blackht)coordinate(FS)
    -| (4\Whitewd,0)coordinate(SOL) -- cycle;
    \drawaccidental{FS}{F}{SOL}{FS0}
    \drawname{FA}
    
    \draw (SOL) -- ++(0,\Whitefrontht) -| (FS0) -- ++(\Backwdii,0) -- ++(0,-\Blackht)coordinate(GS)
    -| (5\Whitewd,0)coordinate(LA) -- cycle;
    \drawaccidental{GS}{SOL}{LA}{GS0}
    \drawname{SOL}
    
    \draw (LA) -- ++(0,\Whitefrontht) -| (GS0) -- ++(\Backwdii,0) -- ++(0,-\Blackht)coordinate(AS)
    -| (6\Whitewd,0)coordinate(SI) -- cycle;
    \drawaccidental{AS}{LA}{SI}{AS0}
    \drawname{LA}
    
    \draw (SI) -- ++(0,\Whitefrontht) -| (AS0) -- ++(\Backwdi,0) -- ++(0,-\FronttoBack) -- cycle;
    \drawname{SI}
    }

\begin{document}        
    
    %%%%Dibujo del piano
    \setlength{\CtoBwd}{6.5in} 
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\tmpwd}{\CtoBwd/5880}
    \setlength{\Whitewd}{\dimexpr \tmpwd*840\relax}
    \setlength{\Blackwd}{\dimexpr \tmpwd*490\relax}
    \setlength{\Blackht}{1.75in}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \setlength{\Whitefrontht}{1in}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \setlength{\FronttoBack}{\dimexpr \Whitefrontht + \Blackht\relax}
    \setlength{\Backwdi}{\dimexpr\tmpwd*455\relax}
    \setlength{\Backwdii}{\dimexpr\tmpwd*490\relax}
    \setlength{\Backwdiii}{\dimexpr\tmpwd*525\relax}
        
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7,rounded corners=4pt,  tonos/.style={draw,text width=1.2cm, fill=#1, align =center, font=\bfseries}]% changed <<<
        \foreach \oct in {0}{% for 4 octaves; vary at will
            \begin{scope}[xshift=\oct*\CtoBwd]
                \drawkeyboard
            \end{scope}
        }
        %Poniendo etiquetas
        \node[tonos={red!20}]   (tonoCD) at (2.35,-1.0) {1 tono};
        \node[tonos={red!20}]   (tonoDE) at (4.7,-1.0) {1 tono};
        \node[tonos={yellow!70}](semiTonoEF) at (7.1,-1.0) {1/2 tono};
        \node[tonos={red!20}]   (tonoFG) at (9.4,-1.0) {1 tono};
        \node[tonos={red!20}]   (tonoGA) at (11.8,-1.0) {1 tono};
        \node[tonos={red!20}]   (tonoAB) at (14.2,-1.0) {1 tono};
        \node[tonos={yellow!70}](semiTonoBC) at (16.5,-1.0) {1/2 tono};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

According Sigur code solution, now item 1 has been solved as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras


%Rutinas para dibujar el piano
\newlength{\CtoBwd}%% Width of 7 adjacent white (natural) keys
\newlength{\Whitewd}%% Width of a natural key
\newlength{\Blackwd}%% Width of a black key
\newlength{\Whitefrontht}%% Distance from front of white key to black key
\newlength{\Backwdi}%% <<-- See below
\newlength{\Backwdii}%% <<-- See below
\newlength{\Backwdiii}%% <<-- See below
\newlength{\FronttoBack}%% Total length of a natural key
\newlength{\Blackht}%% Length of a black key

%% http://datagenetics.com/blog/may32016/index.html

\NewDocumentCommand{\drawaccidental}{mmmm}{% Lower left, sharp name, flat name, coordinate name for upper right of accidental
    \draw[fill=black] (#1)
        rectangle node[white,text width=\Backwdii,align=center]
            {\bfseries\huge#2${}^\sharp$\\[1ex]#3${}^\flat$}
        ++ (\Blackwd,\Blackht)coordinate (#4);
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\drawname}{m}{% Coordinate name of lower left of key and name of key
    \node at ($(#1) + (\Whitewd/2,\Whitefrontht/2)$) {\bfseries\Huge#1};
}

%% f b = \Backwdi
%% cs ds fs gs as = \Backwdii
%% d g a = \Backwdii
%% c e = \Backwdiii

\NewDocumentCommand{\drawkeyboard}{}{%
    \draw (0,0)coordinate(C) -- ++(0,\FronttoBack) -- ++(\Backwdiii,0) --
        ++(0,-\Blackht)coordinate(CS) -| (\Whitewd,0)coordinate(D) -- cycle;
    \drawaccidental{CS}{C}{D}{CS0}
    \drawname{C}

    \draw (D) -- ++(0,\Whitefrontht) -| (CS0) -- ++(\Backwdii,0) -- ++(0,-\Blackht)coordinate(DS)
        -| (2\Whitewd,0)coordinate(E) -- cycle;
    \drawaccidental{DS}{D}{E}{DS0}
    \drawname{D}

    \draw (E) -- ++(0,\Whitefrontht) -| (DS0) -- ++(\Backwdiii,0) -- ++(0,-\FronttoBack)coordinate(F)
        -- cycle;
    \drawname {E}

    \draw (F) -- ++(0,\FronttoBack) -- ++(\Backwdi,0) -- ++(0,-\Blackht)coordinate(FS)
        -| (4\Whitewd,0)coordinate(G) -- cycle;
    \drawaccidental{FS}{F}{G}{FS0}
    \drawname{F}

    \draw (G) -- ++(0,\Whitefrontht) -| (FS0) -- ++(\Backwdii,0) -- ++(0,-\Blackht)coordinate(GS)
        -| (5\Whitewd,0)coordinate(A) -- cycle;
    \drawaccidental{GS}{G}{A}{GS0}
    \drawname{G}

    \draw (A) -- ++(0,\Whitefrontht) -| (GS0) -- ++(\Backwdii,0) -- ++(0,-\Blackht)coordinate(AS)
    -| (6\Whitewd,0)coordinate(B) -- cycle;
    \drawaccidental{AS}{A}{B}{AS0}
    \drawname{A}

    \draw (B) -- ++(0,\Whitefrontht) -| (AS0) -- ++(\Backwdi,0) -- ++(0,-\FronttoBack) -- cycle;
    \drawname{B}
}

\begin{document}

%Dibujo del piano
\setlength{\CtoBwd}{6.5in} %% This varies between 160mm to 167mm depending upon manufacturer
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\tmpwd}{\CtoBwd/5880}\typeout{\tmpwd!!!!}
\setlength{\Whitewd}{\dimexpr \tmpwd*840\relax}
\setlength{\Blackwd}{\dimexpr \tmpwd*490\relax}
\setlength{\Blackht}{3.75in}
\setlength{\Whitefrontht}{2in}
\setlength{\FronttoBack}{\dimexpr \Whitefrontht + \Blackht\relax}
\setlength{\Backwdi}{\dimexpr\tmpwd*455\relax}
\setlength{\Backwdii}{\dimexpr\tmpwd*490\relax}
\setlength{\Backwdiii}{\dimexpr\tmpwd*525\relax}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7,rounded corners=4pt]
    %\foreach \oct in {0,...,3}{% for 4 octaves; vary at will
    \foreach \oct in {0}{% for 4 octaves; vary at will
        \begin{scope}[xshift=\oct*\CtoBwd]
        \drawkeyboard
        \end{scope}
    }
    %Poniendo etiquetas
    \node[text width=1cm,align=center,draw,fill=red!20] (tonoCD) at (2.35,-1.0) {\textbf{1 tono}};
    \node[text width=1cm,align=center,draw,fill=red!20] (tonoDE) at (4.7,-1.0) {\textbf{1 tono}};
    \node[text width=1cm,align=center,draw,fill=yellow!70] (semiTonoEF) at (7.1,-1.0) {\textbf{$1/2$ tono}};
    \node[text width=1cm,align=center,draw,fill=red!20] (tonoFG) at (9.4,-1.0) {\textbf{1 tono}};
    \node[text width=1cm,align=center,draw,fill=red!20] (tonoGA) at (11.8,-1.0) {\textbf{1 tono}};
    \node[text width=1cm,align=center,draw,fill=red!20] (tonoAB) at (14.2,-1.0) {\textbf{1 tono}};
    \node[text width=1cm,align=center,draw,fill=yellow!70] (semiTonoBC) at (16.5,-1.0) {\textbf{$1/2$ tono}};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

The output is as follow:
[image: solved item 1]